# Normal Force Components For Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation

[image: Problem]

[image: Diagram]

Hey, I was working on a problem for physics and couldn't wrap my head around it at all.
I was looking at this diagram that I found online [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoHS0.png) but it doesn't make sense to me on what the x component of the normal force does. I know that the Y component of the normal is opposite of the force of gravity, and is the same magnitude just opposite direction. if the normal force is what's causing it move in a circle, what does the Nx mean and why is it set equal to centripetal force and where does tan(θ) come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal force here is the force exerted by the wire on the bead, directed perpendicular to the point of contact between the bead and the wire, which is toward the center of the wire loop.  This force can be broken up into horizontal and vertical components.

If the bead is moving in a horizontal circle (and therefore not accelerating vertically), the vertical forces acting on the object must cancel, and so the gravitational force and vertical component of the wire-on-bead normal force must cancel.  The only remaining piece is the horizontal component of the normal force, directed horizontally toward the center of the circle in which the bead is moving.

Finally, if an object is moving in a circle of radius $r$ with a constant speed $v$, we know that its acceleration is $v^2/r$ (known as the *centripetal* acceleration), and thus the net force on the object must have the value$^1$
$$
F_{\textrm{net}} = ma = m\frac{v^2}{r}\,.
$$
We know from the above that the $F_{\textrm{net}} = N_x$, because $N_x$ is the remaining force after all the forces have been added together. In other words, the horizontal component of the normal force exerted by the wire on the bead provides the force required to keep the bead moving in a circle at constant speed.

<sub>$^1$ There could be some confusion here. To be clear: we are *inferring* that there must be a net force with magnitude $mv^2/r$ from the observation that the bead is moving at speed $v$ in a circle of radius $r$, but of course the normal force *comes first*. That is, the bead is set to spinning, and as a consequence, the wire exerts a force on the bead, and this force provides the force necessary to keep the object moving in the circle.  The *causal* relationship goes from $N_x$ to $v^2/r$, but we *reason backwards* (in the direction *opposite* the direction of causation) from our observation that the acceleration is $v^2/r$ to solve the problem.</sub>

Comment: I just have one question, If the normal force of the wire on to the bead is pointed  towards the center, how can there also be an x component of the normal force be pointed towards the center as well?

Comment: @Ganish19  Have you distinguished between the centre of the circular loop of wire and the centre of the circular path of the bead?

Comment: @PhilipWood if the bead travels on the same path as loop itself, would the center for both not the be the same?  Sorry for asking a lot of questions, this problem is just completely going over my head.

Comment: The centre of the loop of wire is where $\theta$ is marked on the diagram. The bead doesn't change its position on the wire loop; as the loop rotates about a vertical axis taking the bead with it, the bead's circular path is in a horizontal plane, and the centre of its path is on the same horizontal level as the black blob in the diagram.

Comment: "If the normal force of the wire on to the bead is pointed towards the center..."  It is.  "....how can there also be an x component of the normal force be pointed towards the center as well?"   "also be"    Are you saying that there are two forces in the $x$ direction?

Comment: @PhilipWood So are we saying that that the horizontal path itself from the hoop spinning about he vertical axis is why there the centripetal force is considered Nx? Rather than considering the force directed towards inside the hoop Nx is the force for rotation about the vertical axis?

Comment: @garyp I was confused on why the Nx the horizontal component was the centripetal force because it wasn't pointing towards the center of the circle. But if Im understanding correctly now, The Nx force is the centripetal force for the hoop spinning about the vertical axis.

Comment: "So are we saying that that the horizontal path itself from the hoop spinning about he vertical axis is why there the centripetal force is considered Nx?" Yes the centripetal force is directed to the centre of the bead's path.

Comment: @PhilipWood that makes perfect sense now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

**A normal force does not depend on gravity.** It is *not* true that the vertical component of the normal vector must be equal to gravity. The normal force is just a "holding-back" reaction force that comes into existance to prevent a surface from breaking. Sure, if a book is resting on a table, then the upwards normal force equals gravity, because gravity must be balanced out. But try pushing down on it. Now the normal force increases because there is more total force that must be counteracted - but the gravitational force is still the same.

Now, imagine sitting in an airplane during a vertical loop. You might have your head downwards at some point during this circular loop. You feel squeezed into your seat. The normal force "holds back" by pushing on you so the bottom of the airplane doesn't break. This normal force might not be vertical - it might be at some other angler, possibly inwards into the circular motion.

At this angle it might have a vertical component and a horizontal component that together constitute the actual normal force. There is no inherent difference between the two components. You (or your textbook) have just arbitrarily chosen to resolve them along the vertical and horizontal directions - but there is no inherent reason for doing so.

Now, if the seat did *not* produce a normal force to push on you, then you would break through the bottom of the plane and just continue flying straight ahead. The fact that you are actually following the plane around is *due to the normal force*. At any moment your body has a velocity in some direction, and the normal force is *pushing at an angle*, thus *turning* your velocity. In the next moment your velocity has turned a bit, but the normal force has turned as well so that it still causes turning yet again!

In this way, your velocity keeps turning. You are moving in a circle. At any moment it is in fact only the part of the normal force which is point perpendicularly inwards that causes turning - any part of it which pulls along with your velocity, tangentially, does not cause turning. That is why we always looking for this inwards-point component during circular motion. And whatever this inwards-pointing component is, we call it **the centripetal force**.

Where the $\tan(\theta)$ is purely a mathematical/geometric question. Consider the angle of the inwards force component, and that angle might turn out to use this tangent relation.

Answer (score 3):

$\vec W$ and $\vec N$ must add together (head of arrow representing one of them to tail of arrow representing the other) to make the necessary (horizontal) centripetal force. Just sketch the vector diagram! You'll see where $\tan \theta$ comes from.

No need to fiddle about with components (though $\vec N_x$ must be the centripetal force, and $\vec N_y$ must be equal and opposite to $\vec W$).